# how show all nearby location?

Tags: android

I have to show in a listview all near location where device currently available ,suppose my device in which my application is installed situated in noida location then I want to show all near location of noida in a listview.I have search on google but unable to find any needful tutorial please anyone help me.

Comment: are you using Android google maps ?

Comment: yes I am using google map but I have no Idea how to do this please guide me

Comment: You'll need some sort of database of points of interest I guess.  But this question is far too unclear to ask here on SO - we aren't supposed to have to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Google place API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches). Please also see the following:
[Android Development – Part 1: Using Google’s Places API to Develop Compelling Location Based Mobile Applications](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/)

[Android Development – Part 2: Using Google’s Places API to Develop Compelling Location Based Mobile Application](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-2-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/)s